# UBUNTU 16.04 minimal: Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:00:08.0: Unknown Error

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

After I had installed an ubuntu 16.04 minimal version, I intended to install NVIDIA driver, cuda and cudnn drivers. so I used [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) reference and after downloading all necessary files like:

```
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.59.run
cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run
```

Then after giving permission to run, I used the command `sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.59.run` to install the nvidia driver. I also installed cuda with the same procedure.

Unfortunately when I use the `nvidia-smi`, I get this error

```
Unable to determine the device handle for GPU 0000:00:08.0: Unknown Error
```

I also used the debian packages and got the same results.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu on a virtual machine?

Comment: Its installed on server and I connect to it by MobaXterm

Comment: Check those links, they might be helpful: [KVM GPU passthrough](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/kvm-gpu-passthrough-solved/110696) and [nvidia-smi reports Unable to determine the device handle for GPU](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/982322/linux/nvidia-smi-reports-unable-to-determine-the-device-handle-for-gpu/)